# How to display on screen multiple values in one column using php?

Tags: php, implode

I have 2 dropdowns. Whatever I have to select from first dropdown and second dropdown both value I have to display on the screen. I mean I have to display in the same column with a comma(,).  Would you help me in this?

```
   <form action="#" method="post">

        <select name="ab[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="ab[]">
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $ab=$_POST['ab'];
    $a=array($ab);
    print_r($a);// I am able to display value here but implode is not working.

    $b = implode(',',$a);
     print_r($b);
}
```

Comment: The `$a` array adds an unneeded extra level of wrapping around the values. Use `$ab` instead of `$a` and it will do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need this

```
 $a=array($ab);   //remove this line
```

If you need that for any other purpose then change your code to this

```
$b = implode(',',$a[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr. Rahul Singh. Working great. but If i remove  $a=array($ab);  this then getting error

Comment: Error is implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: If you removed $a=array($ab); then you can not use $a as you not defined this so implode $ab not $a. So you need to change to 
 $b = implode(',',$ab);

Comment: Yes, Mr.Rahul, That I know  I changed that but still getting error.

Comment: your code should be this :
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $ab=$_POST['ab'];
    $b = implode(',',$ab);
     print_r($b);
}

Comment: Right. Actually, There was some cache issue. Working perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$ab should be already an array, you do not have to do $a=array($ab).

it should be enough to do:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $ab=$_POST['ab'];

    $b = implode(',',$ab);
    print_r($b);
}
```

The [] in  name="ab[]" is telling already to take is as an array.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Andi, Your code is also working. Upvote from my side